# JS Event Calendar, to handle multiple lineedit events with their own task sets as checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a simple calendar app that stores locally within itself its events, and tasks

Currently it is using a single text box to store event data and does not allow task handling within the event. just a large text editable box for text input only.

So instead of having a single text box for all events on a date, how do change my code so it handles single lineedit events up to 20 events during a day each with their own associated task list

I.E: on 22nd September there are four events Event 1, Event 2, Event 3, Event 4. currently this stores as noted above single line of events not separated at all. I want to try to have individual events with their own task sets.

So example I want to try to do the following;
on click of a date within the month example 22nd Sept 22

lineEdit Event 1, Checkbox Task 1, Checkbox Task 2, Checkbox Task 3

lineEdit Event 2, Checkbox Task 1, Checkbox Task 2, Checkbox Task 3

lineEdit Event 3, Checkbox Task 1, Checkbox Task 2, Checkbox Task 3

lineEdit Event 4, Checkbox Task 1, Checkbox Task 2, Checkbox Task 3

kind of something like this;

```
<textarea id="evt-details" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="Task 1"><label>Task2</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="Task 2"><label>Task2</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="Task 3"><label>Task 3</label><br>
```

But cleaner to allow multiple individual events and allow them to be individually edited, modified and deleted and still allowing for the expansion of the calendar squares to display all events on the day if multiples and I ideally want to show the task completed either by colour code- or when ticked write it beside the event "task 1 complete" for an example..

etc etc.

```js
var cal = {
  // (A) PROPERTIES
  // (A1) COMMON CALENDAR
  sMon : false, // Week start on Monday?
  mName : ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"], // Month Names

  // (A2) CALENDAR DATA
  data : null, // Events for the selected period
  sDay : 0, sMth : 0, sYear : 0, // Current selected day, month, year

  // (A3) COMMON HTML ELEMENTS
  hMth : null, hYear : null, // month/year selector
  hForm : null, hfHead : null, hfDate : null, hfTxt : null, hfDel : null, // event form

  // (B) INIT CALENDAR
  init : () => {
    // (B1) GET + SET COMMON HTML ELEMENTS
    cal.hMth = document.getElementById("cal-mth");
    cal.hYear = document.getElementById("cal-yr");
    cal.hForm = document.getElementById("cal-event");
    cal.hfHead = document.getElementById("evt-head");
    cal.hfDate = document.getElementById("evt-date");
    cal.hfTxt = document.getElementById("evt-details");
    cal.hfDel = document.getElementById("evt-del");
    document.getElementById("evt-close").onclick = cal.close;
    cal.hfDel.onclick = cal.del;
    cal.hForm.onsubmit = cal.save;

    // (B2) DATE NOW
    let now = new Date(),
        nowMth = now.getMonth(),
        nowYear = parseInt(now.getFullYear());

    // (B3) APPEND MONTHS SELECTOR
    for (let i=0; i<12; i++) {
      let opt = document.createElement("option");
      opt.value = i;
      opt.innerHTML = cal.mName[i];
      if (i==nowMth) { opt.selected = true; }
      cal.hMth.appendChild(opt);
    }
    cal.hMth.onchange = cal.list;

    // (B4) APPEND YEARS SELECTOR
    // Set to 10 years range. Change this as you like.
    for (let i=nowYear-10; i<=nowYear+10; i++) {
      let opt = document.createElement("option");
      opt.value = i;
      opt.innerHTML = i;
      if (i==nowYear) { opt.selected = true; }
      cal.hYear.appendChild(opt);
    }
    cal.hYear.onchange = cal.list;

    // (B5) START - DRAW CALENDAR
    cal.list();
  },

  // (C) DRAW CALENDAR FOR SELECTED MONTH
  list : () => {
    // (C1) BASIC CALCULATIONS - DAYS IN MONTH, START + END DAY
    // Note - Jan is 0 & Dec is 11
    // Note - Sun is 0 & Sat is 6
    cal.sMth = parseInt(cal.hMth.value); // selected month
    cal.sYear = parseInt(cal.hYear.value); // selected year
    let daysInMth = new Date(cal.sYear, cal.sMth+1, 0).getDate(), // number of days in selected month
        startDay = new Date(cal.sYear, cal.sMth, 1).getDay(), // first day of the month
        endDay = new Date(cal.sYear, cal.sMth, daysInMth).getDay(), // last day of the month
        now = new Date(), // current date
        nowMth = now.getMonth(), // current month
        nowYear = parseInt(now.getFullYear()), // current year
        nowDay = cal.sMth==nowMth && cal.sYear==nowYear ? now.getDate() : null ;

    // (C2) LOAD DATA FROM LOCALSTORAGE
    cal.data = localStorage.getItem("cal-" + cal.sMth + "-" + cal.sYear);
    if (cal.data==null) {
      localStorage.setItem("cal-" + cal.sMth + "-" + cal.sYear, "{}");
      cal.data = {};
    } else { cal.data = JSON.parse(cal.data); }

    // (C3) DRAWING CALCULATIONS
    // Blank squares before start of month
    let squares = [];
    if (cal.sMon && startDay != 1) {
      let blanks = startDay==0 ? 7 : startDay ;
      for (let i=1; i<blanks; i++) { squares.push("b"); }
    }
    if (!cal.sMon && startDay != 0) {
      for (let i=0; i<startDay; i++) { squares.push("b"); }
    }

    // Days of the month
    for (let i=1; i<=daysInMth; i++) { squares.push(i); }

    // Blank squares after end of month
    if (cal.sMon && endDay != 0) {
      let blanks = endDay==6 ? 1 : 7-endDay;
      for (let i=0; i<blanks; i++) { squares.push("b"); }
    }
    if (!cal.sMon && endDay != 6) {
      let blanks = endDay==0 ? 6 : 6-endDay;
      for (let i=0; i<blanks; i++) { squares.push("b"); }
    }

    // (C4) DRAW HTML CALENDAR
    // Get container
    let container = document.getElementById("cal-container"),
    cTable = document.createElement("table");
    cTable.id = "calendar";
    container.innerHTML = "";
    container.appendChild(cTable);

    // First row - Day names
    let cRow = document.createElement("tr"),
        days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat"];
    if (cal.sMon) { days.push(days.shift()); }
    for (let d of days) {
      let cCell = document.createElement("td");
      cCell.innerHTML = d;
      cRow.appendChild(cCell);
    }
    cRow.classList.add("head");
    cTable.appendChild(cRow);

    // Days in Month
    let total = squares.length;
    cRow = document.createElement("tr");
    cRow.classList.add("day");
    for (let i=0; i<total; i++) {
      let cCell = document.createElement("td");
      if (squares[i]=="b") { cCell.classList.add("blank"); }
      else {
        if (nowDay==squares[i]) { cCell.classList.add("today"); }
        cCell.innerHTML = `<div class="dd">${squares[i]}</div>`;
        if (cal.data[squares[i]]) {
          cCell.innerHTML += "<div class='evt'>" + cal.data[squares[i]] + "</div>";
        }
        cCell.onclick = () => { cal.show(cCell); };
      }
      cRow.appendChild(cCell);
      if (i!=0 && (i+1)%7==0) {
        cTable.appendChild(cRow);
        cRow = document.createElement("tr");
        cRow.classList.add("day");
      }
    }

    // (C5) REMOVE ANY PREVIOUS ADD/EDIT EVENT DOCKET
    cal.close();
  },

  // (D) SHOW EDIT EVENT DOCKET FOR SELECTED DAY
  show : (el) => {
    // (D1) FETCH EXISTING DATA
    cal.sDay = el.getElementsByClassName("dd")[0].innerHTML;
    let isEdit = cal.data[cal.sDay] !== undefined ;

    // (D2) UPDATE EVENT FORM
    cal.hfTxt.value = isEdit ? cal.data[cal.sDay] : "" ;
    cal.hfHead.innerHTML = isEdit ? "EDIT EVENT" : "ADD EVENT" ;
    cal.hfDate.innerHTML = `${cal.sDay} ${cal.mName[cal.sMth]} ${cal.sYear}`;
    if (isEdit) { cal.hfDel.classList.remove("ninja"); }
    else { cal.hfDel.classList.add("ninja"); }
    cal.hForm.classList.remove("ninja");
  },

  // (E) CLOSE EVENT DOCKET
  close : () => {
    cal.hForm.classList.add("ninja");
  },

  // (F) SAVE EVENT
  save : () => {
    cal.data[cal.sDay] = cal.hfTxt.value;
    localStorage.setItem(`cal-${cal.sMth}-${cal.sYear}`, JSON.stringify(cal.data));
    cal.list();
    return false;
  },

  // (G) DELETE EVENT FOR SELECTED DATE
  del : () => { if (confirm("Delete event?")) {
    delete cal.data[cal.sDay];
    localStorage.setItem(`cal-${cal.sMth}-${cal.sYear}`, JSON.stringify(cal.data));
    cal.list();
  }}
};
window.addEventListener("load", cal.init);
```

```css
/* (A) ENTIRE PAGE */
#cal-wrap * { font-family: arial, sans-serif; }
.ninja { display: none !important; }

/* (B) CONTAINER */
#cal-wrap { max-width: 900px; }

/* (C) PERIOD SELECTOR */
#cal-date { display: flex; }
#cal-mth, #cal-yr {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 0;
}

/* (D) CALENDAR */
#calendar {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#calendar tr.head td {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000000;
  background: #CCFFFF;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
#calendar tr.day td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 14.28%;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#calendar tr.day td:hover {
  background: #fff9e4;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#calendar tr td.blank {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
#calendar tr td.today {
  background: #ffdede;
}
#calendar .dd {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #999;
}
#calendar .evt {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #ff5d5d;
}

/* (E) ADD/EDIT EVENT */
#cal-event {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#cal-event h1 {
  color: #333;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#evt-date {
  color: #555;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
#cal-event textarea {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  min-height: 200px;
}
#cal-event input[type=button], #cal-event input[type=submit] {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 0;
  background: #ea4c4c;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Javascript Calendar</title>
    <link href="calendar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script async src="calendar.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="cal-wrap">
      <!-- (A) PERIOD SELECTOR -->
      <div id="cal-date">
        <select id="cal-mth"></select>
        <select id="cal-yr"></select>
      </div>

      <!-- (B) CALENDAR -->
      <div id="cal-container"></div>

      <!-- (C) EVENT FORM -->
      <form id="cal-event">
        <h1 id="evt-head"></h1>
        <div id="evt-date"></div>
        <textarea id="evt-details" required></textarea>
        <input id="evt-close" type="button" value="Close"/>
        <input id="evt-del" type="button" value="Delete"/>
        <input id="evt-save" type="submit" value="Save"/>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a fine start.

You'll just store more information on your localstorage saves like

```
[{
  "text_area" : "Text area for Nov 6",
  "tasks":[
    {
      "label" : "Label 1",
      "value" : "Value 1"
    },
    {
      "label" : "Label 2",
      "value" : "Value 2"
    },
    {
      "label" : "Label 3",
      "value" : "Value 3"
    }
  ]
},{
  "text_area" : "Another text area for Nov 6",
  "tasks":[
    {
      "label" : "Label 1",
      "value" : "Value 1"
    },
    {
      "label" : "Label 2",
      "value" : "Value 2"
    },
    {
      "label" : "Label 3",
      "value" : "Value 3"
    }
  ]
}]
```

and change your form to have a container

```
<form id="cal-event">
        <h1 id="evt-head"></h1>
        <div id="evt-date"></div>
        <div id="form-container"></div>
        <input id="evt-close" type="button" value="Close"/>
        <input id="evt-del" type="button" value="Delete"/>
        <input id="evt-save" type="submit" value="Save"/>
      </form>
```

and then in your show method you'd do something like

```
show: (el) => {
    //...
    let HTML  = ''
    cal.data.forEach(taskGroup => {
        // define a new text area
        HTML += `<textarea>${taskGroup.text_area}</textarea>`
        taskGroup.tasks.forEach(task => {
            HTML += `<input type="checkbox" value="${task.value}"><label>${task.label}</label>`
        })
        //...
    })
    document.getElementById('form-container').innerHTML = HTML;
    //...
}
```

The gist is your gonna allow your data to dictate more and more what your page looks and feels like by describing more JSON.

As far as your calendar, to maximize the space and have more flexibility on amount of content you can shove in, you may want to get away from `<tables>` and work with something like css grid https://learncssgrid.com/

Please take this code as pseudo code to give you some ideas. Happy programming.

Comment: Thank you for that!

I am still learning and certainly learning about grids currently so will look to implement that!

As for your first line of code: the one starting "date" :6

Where am I sticking that in relation to the rest, I just simply can't see it.

Comment: I personally wouldn't even use a date on the localstorage data. You already have the date on the localstorage key, the data should be specific to the content inside the date.

Comment: @Pixal I updated my answer to hopefully reflect more of what I mean

Comment: Thank you I get what you are talking about. I am still unsure though in where that first section of code should be placed within.

Comment: @Pixal the first section is not code. It is what should be stored in local storage.

Comment: That makes sense now, I was wondering why I felt like it didn't fit within the script. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248210/discussion-between-pixal-and-rager).